# Inspect FormData object with console.log

Tags: javascript, html

I've created `FormData` object created like that:

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append('image', input[0].files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')
```

Now when i try to inspect it like that

```
console.log(data)
```

i get empty `FormData` object (the only propery is `__proto__`). There is no `image` and `user` properties.

Comment: `console.log(Array.from(data));`

Comment: @ponury-kostek Ok, thx. it works. But my question is now why does simple console.log works with objects like user = {name: "John"} but doesn't with FormData?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should have to iterate over [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) . `FormData` is type of `object` so rather than logging itself you have to get values by `get` method or iterate over `entries` . Here is how.

```js
var data = new FormData()
//data.append('image', input[0].files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')
   
for(var pair of data.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}
```

If you want to fetch only one value at a time , you can have by `key`

```
  console.log(data.get('user'));
  // 'hubot'
```

**Edit**

Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected. [More from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) . So if you want to simply log

```
   // console.log(...data);
```

Comment: Ok, thx. it works. But my question is now why does simple `console.log` works with objects like `user = {name: "John"}` but doesn't with FormData?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
for (var d of data.entries()) {
    console.log(d); 
    // Do whatever with d
}
```

Comment: Ok, thx. it works. But my question is now why does simple console.log works with objects like user = {name: "John"} but doesn't with FormData?